# Merge account request link on user page

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have seen people asking of merging their accounts on meta. I think SO should provide merge account request link on user's home page. By clicking on it user can request merging accounts by giving account's link he want to merge. [Or something similar] This way may be people stop making requests in questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is really necessary. E-Mailing the team or asking a question here are perfectly fine ways to deal with it. Also, an explicit "request merge" link would almost certainly increase the number of fraudulent requests.

Comment: How does you saying to email the team on meta stop new users "making requests in questions"?

Comment: @Ian I expect most people will just E-Mail the team anyway. And for the rest, what is the problem with users making requests in questions? Is somebody occasionally asking for a merge that big a nuisance? I think not.